# Css print control other than page-break-after & page-break-before

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I'm designing a web interface that will print barcodes on an Avery sheet of labels. What's the best route for making sure everything lines up exactly on every label (would using physical measurements such as inches or centimeters help?) and more importantly - how can I ensure that each set of labels resides on its own page without bleeding into another page?

My current solution uses a table for each page that is sized to match the labels (as best as I possibly could, Printing an excess number of pages eventually will bump the barcodes off of the labels) this small bump prevents me from adding information under the barcodes, as it makes the bump worse. I've looked into page-break-after and page-break-before but setting them seems to have no effect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some code please?... And you say "interface", yet I'm envisioning a blank page with barcodes, but I can't be sure since you didn't supply the data. However, when it comes to printing and the web, they are of two worlds. One is 72dpi and one is more dpi than that. I guess the average printer uses 120dpi. For this reason, you can probably not accurately predict the behavior on every system, every time. But if you supply some code I'm sure it's to make it work "almost always"...

Answer (score 0):

Even though you didn't supply any code, I'll take a stab at it:

First, get Selectivizr and jQuery so that IE can read the CSS3 stuff we need:

- Selectivizr: http://selectivizr.com/
- jQuery: http://jquery.com/

Here is the HTML I quickly set up:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="barcode">
            <img src="/path/to/barcodes/1.jpg" />
            <span class="descr">Some descriptive text</span>
        </div>

        <div class="barcode">
            <img src="/path/to/barcodes/1.jpg" />
            <span class="descr">Some descriptive text</span>
        </div>

        <div class="barcode">
            <img src="/path/to/barcodes/1.jpg" />
            <span class="descr">Some descriptive text</span>
        </div>

        <div class="barcode">
            <img src="/path/to/barcodes/1.jpg" />
            <span class="descr">Some descriptive text</span>
        </div>

        <div class="barcode">
            <img src="/path/to/barcodes/1.jpg" />
            <span class="descr">Some descriptive text</span>
        </div>

        <div class="barcode">
            <img src="/path/to/barcodes/1.jpg" />
            <span class="descr">Some descriptive text</span>
        </div>

        <div class="barcode">
            <img src="/path/to/barcodes/1.jpg" />
            <span class="descr">Some descriptive text</span>
        </div>

        <div class="barcode">
            <img src="/path/to/barcodes/1.jpg" />
            <span class="descr">Some descriptive text</span>
        </div>

        <div class="barcode">
            <img src="/path/to/barcodes/1.jpg" />
            <span class="descr">Some descriptive text</span>
        </div>

        <div class="barcode">
            <img src="/path/to/barcodes/1.jpg" />
            <span class="descr">Some descriptive text</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS you need:

```
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #wrapper { width: 100%; display: block; }
    .barcode { width: 30%; float: left; margin-bottom: 50px; }
    .barcode img { display: block; width: 150px; height: 150px; margin: 0 auto 10px auto; } /* set to whatever the barcodes will be in size */
    .barcode span { display: block; text-align: center; }
    #wrapper div.barcode:nth-child(3n+4) { clear: left;  }
    #wrapper div.barcode:nth-child(6n+6) { page-break-after: always; background: #000; } /* Use 9n+9 to page break after each 9th item. */
```

This will page break after each 6th barcode. If I understand your question correctly, this "should always work".

Of course I'm limited in the amount of systems I have for testing... :)